# Setting up a Sky: bpy.context.world = None

Tags: python, scripting, world

I am trying to set up a sky in my script using 
`bpy.context.scene.world.use_sky_paper = True` which results in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'use_sky_paper'
```

Why does `bpy.context.scene.world` return `None`? Is there some setup required for the `world`?

I encountered a similar problem, when trying to see which area is active via `bpy.context.area.type` where `area` is `None`.

**Update**: `bpy.context.area` is always `None` when running script headless.

Comment: Your assignments working as expected for Blender 2.78c... Also `context.area.type` is never `none`. Cycles or Internal? What blender version? Are you trying to execute that commands headless (without UI)?

Comment: I am using blender 2.78 with internal render. I am not scripting inside blender but using an external python script executed with `blender --background --python <name_of_script>`. Executing `print(bpy.context.area)` prints `None` to the console.

Comment: Since you are running these commands headless and [`bpy.context.area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area) returns the *active area* of the UI, it's totally obvious why the property is `none`. Also I have no problems printing `World.use_sky_paper` to the command line. Does this [example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81981/31447) helps?

Comment: ok. So that part of my question is answered. The mode of the object is already object mode. The error persists when inserting `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')` as suggested by the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not set `scene.world` is None.  Simply set it, for example to a world named "World" with `scene.world = bpy.data.worlds.get("World")` , or create a new one.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

if scene.world is None:
    # create a new world
    new_world = bpy.data.worlds.new("New World")
    new_world.use_sky_paper = True
    scene.world = new_world
```

Comment: I am at the moment on another device: On my MacBook, it seems `scene.world` is already defined from the beginning. So I can check your solution only tomorrow. Any idea why that can depend on the PC, if blender version and script are the same?

Comment: My guess would be to check `startup.blend`, you may have inadvertently removed world from scene.

Comment: Solution works. Problem was indeed with `startup.blender`

Comment: Is this a pre-2.8 fix?