# Convert world.light_settings to Blender 2.8 (bpy)

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, light, world

I'm trying to fix:

```
bpy.context.scene.world.light_settings.use_environment_light = True
bpy.context.scene.world.light_settings.environment_energy = energy
bpy.context.scene.world.light_settings.environment_color = 'PLAIN'
```

to make them work in blender 2.8. I read [Setting up a Sky: bpy.context.world = None](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89096/setting-up-a-sky-bpy-context-world-none), but my `bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree` is None. How would I set up a node tree and add the Background node?

It seems like the correct code should be something like `bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes['Background'].inputs['Strength'].default_value = energy`, but I can't figure out how to make the `node_tree`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please explain what you *actually* want to do? Setting up a custom environment using a hdri or just a plain color and up the strength?

Comment: Once the world is created, just add something like: world.use_nodes = True This will create the node tree.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132271/blender-2-8-get-environment-texture-path-from-ui-to-python-script

Comment: @brockmann i am trying to convert a neural net script, so i am not really sure what its supposed to do exactly - i just want to convert these lines as close to the original as possible

Comment: @lemon thank you so much! that worked!